# Mac Searching "Kinds'

Tags: macos, textwrangler

I am trying to uninstall TextWrangler on my mac and have deleted the app and most of the files i could find in the Library however when I go to the search in Finder and start typing "textwrangler" it has the suggestion bar come up with kinds of files and the first one is textwrangler files. I would just like textwrangler to not be on my computer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If those files are associated with TextWrangler, you can reassign them so their "kind" no longer points to the old TextWrangler application.

Locate one or more files associated with TextWrangler in Finder, and view its info (Command-I). You'll see "Open With:" with a dropdown. Choose any other application you wish this file type to be associated with, and then hit the "Change All..." button below that.

Once you disassociate those files from TextWrangler, you shouldn't see any more "kinds" under Spotlight or Finder.

**EDIT:**

You can check for other file associations within `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`. Look for the string `com.barebones.textwrangler` and delete that key.

For example, I have the `.cs` extension mapped to TextWrangler, so its dictionary entry looks like:

```
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerContentTag</key>
        <string>cs</string>
        <key>LSHandlerContentTagClass</key>
        <string>public.filename-extension</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
        <string>com.barebones.textwrangler</string>
    </dict>
```

Simply remove that entire entry for each file that associates with `com.barebones.textwrangler`.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. I changed all the file types to be opened with a different editor and it still has the type associated with it

Comment: Did you select the `Change All...` button when you did, or did you only change the type for a single file?